# SpringBott webSecurityConfig.xml invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I m trying to build a simple SpringBoot application with a login page.

This is my pom.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.18</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>it.michelecastriotta</groupId>
        <artifactId>SimpleWebApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>SimpleWebApp</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <image>
                            <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                        </image>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

In the following path,
src - main - resources

I'm try to create webSecurityConfig.xml file, this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <form-login login-page='/login.html'
                default-target-url="/homepage.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>
```

The Intellij sign error like this:

[image]

If I try to build the application I see the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [webSecurityConfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 30; cvc-elt.1: impossibile trovare la dichiarazione dell'elemento "http".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:402) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:756) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at it.michelecastriotta.SimpleWebApp.SimpleWebAppApplication.main(SimpleWebAppApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: impossibile trovare la dichiarazione dell'elemento "http".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:395) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:283) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1901) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3131) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:851) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:432) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to wrap the config

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login login-page='/login.html' default-target-url="/homepage.html" authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <b:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
</b:beans>
```

Comment: IntelliJ sign the following line as error:

    <bean id="encoder"
          class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

Comment: Thank for asking, now I have no error but if I try to build the application, I can see the following error:
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [webSecurityConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register alias 'springSecurityFilterChain' for name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Alias would override bean definition 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Comment: are you using the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation? if yes try to remove it

Comment: If I try to delete that annotation I don't have that error.